# How to check for std::next(x) pointing to a valid address in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, iterator, runtime-error

Let's say I have the following vector of `std::string` filled with data:

```
std::vector<std::string> japan;
```

And, I search for elements in the vector as follows:

```
std::string where;

auto found = std::find(japan.begin(), japan.end(), where);
```

My issue is that sometimes I need to check the next element in the vector with respect to the "found" one as follows:

```
std::string here = *std::next(found);
```

However, it is not always the case that there is something at the next iterator, and attempting to access such non-existing element gives me "Expression: vector iterator not dereferencable" runtime error message, which is understandable.

My question is, how do I check that `std::next(found)` is a valid address so that I don't raise said error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible to check the validity of a single iterator with only itself, which doesn't contain the necessary information. You will need help from the container. e.g.

```
auto found = std::find(japan.begin(), japan.end(), where);
if (found != japan.end()) {
    // if found is valid
    auto next = std::next(found);
    if (next != japan.end()) {
        // if next is valid
        std::string here = *next;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be solved by using a loop.

```
auto found = std::find(japan.begin(), japan.end(), where);
while (found != japan.end()) {
    // do something with found
    found = std::find(found, japan.end(), where);
}
```

No need for `std::next` here.

Comment: Thank you. The issue is that, what I'm looking for has to be always right after the "found" one.